# Image transfer from server to client through bluetooth in j2me

Tags: image, java-me, bluetooth, transfer

How to transfer text and an image from server(pc) to clients(mobiles) through bluetooth in j2me.

Comment: If anyone knows the code plz .send me to mmt.2508@gmail.com as soon as possible.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for server or client implementation?
For client on j2me try Avetana OBEX:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/avetanaobex